# Is there a (current or historical) word for the extremes on the left-right axis?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there, or has there ever been, an unambiguous word for "the leftmost extreme" or "the rightmost extreme"?  Such words exist for the other two dimensions.

Imagine you are floating in a cube in space.

- You can go *up* until you hit the **top**.
- You can go *down* until you hit the **bottom**.
- You can go *forward* until you hit the **front**.
- You can go *backward* until you hit the (**back/rear**).
- You can go *left* until you hit the _______?
- You can go *right* until you hit the _______?

Comment: ...until you hit (or reach) the **limit** works for all of them. Note that your forward / backward examples don't work well, because 'back' and 'front' usually refer to your own extremities.

Comment: The only words I can come up with are *port* and *starboard*, but those words only make sense if you're on a boat.

Comment: Generally, people don't continuously move left or right, they tend to turn left or right, then move forward. And you can turn left or right as many times as you want.

Comment: Mathematicians have identified *infimums* and *supremums* as, respectively, left and right axis limits, "the greatest (least) element of set **P** that is lower (higher) or equal to the lowest element of set **S**." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: You could refer to "the right side" or"the left side" of an object.

Comment: 'Top', 'bottom', 'front' (= van) etc are all deictic. All lines are infinite, all notional end-points arbitrarily defined (top of a given mountain, not furthest possible distance from 'base' in a vertical line ; 'front' of a bus, say. With the container constraint, the bus for instance, the left edge/side etc are the arbitrarily defined limits.

Comment: Isn't the most telling part of the exposition '… back(ward) until you hit the (back/rear)…'? What does 'rear' really add to that? How could it differ from '… left/right(ward) until you hit the (left/right)…'? Are you trying to have this two ways?

Comment: @EmilKarlsson "Port" and "starboard" don't mean the limit of travel to the left or the right, they just mean left and right.

Comment: Linguistic similarity does not imply similarity in terms of physics. The items explicitly mentioned by the OP are invariant in regard to physics, and so reflect faithfully in a mirror, but a mirror INTERCHANGES left and right. This 'fantasy' status of left and right may be the root reason why it is difficult to satisfy the OP's request.

Comment: Until you hit the side of the cube, left or right. But all these directions are meaningless **except in terms of your own perspective** because a cube is equal on all sides...up, down, left and right only have meaning relative to some other point inside or outside of it....And I'm no maths person. And what axis do you mean anyway?

Comment: Leftmost and rightmost?

Answer (score 14):

Probably not, because left and right are often more vague compared to the other "limits". If you're approaching e.g. a round hill, "top" means the hill's summit, "bottom" generally means the lowest point of the hill that's closest to you. Left and right "limits" don't really mean anything, since you can go around the hill. Same applies to a sphere like the Earth etc. Some objects may have defined left/right "ends" but the word used then is usually specific to the shape. If it's a sheet of paper, the word would be "edge". If it's a building and you're on the ground, the word would be "corner" etc. If you're facing separate objects, like a row of columns, you can say "the leftmost/rightmost column".

Comment: Yes. As usual it depends on context. The question mentions floating in a cube in space, but how often does that happen?

Comment: It was the example I came up with to clarify the question. Perhaps only on the International Space Station at present?

Comment: It depends on your perspective and human perspective for all this is given by 1) gravity and 2) the position they face in terms of left/right of their own body on Earth. Floating in space still requires a point of view for left and right that cannot be given by a cube since it is all the same on all sides.

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that you are confined in a cube or cuboidal walled room or enclosure looking straight ahead or floating in a spaceship...

You can go up until you hit the top structure or roof.

You can go down until you hit the bottom structure or floor.

You can go forward until you hit the front wall.

You can go backward until you hit the (back/rear) wall.

You can go left until you hit the   left wall.

You can go right until you hit the right wall.

These are 3 dimensions or 6 axes if sense of movement vector is considered.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single word for these, we would just say "left face" or "right face".

If, instead of a solid like a cube, we were talking about something more linear (like a line, or a road on a map), you could say "beginning" for the left extreme and "end" for the right extreme. Absent other context, we tend to consider progression from left to right (west to east on maps), similar to reading. But note that this would change if the direction of motion along the line is known; then "beginning" is wherever you started, and "end" is the destination.

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine you are floating in a cube in space.

*Port* and *starboard* work well with marine vessels and aircraft who often deal with such orientation issues.
I presume space personnel use similar terms to aircraft folks.

[Port and starboard unambiguously refer to the left and right side of the vessel, not the observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_and_starboard#Side).
[Why is port-starboard terminology used in aviation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15139/26231).

port/starboard, fore/aft, top/below

"You can go (left) until you hit the cube's [portside](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/portside#Noun)."

Comment: But are they extremes?

Comment: @Joachim, Yes. the port/starboard of the craft and the P/S of the cube are its sides.

Comment: It's not just the extremes. The entire left half of the ship is called "port", not just the hull. In maritime language they're essentially synonymous with "left" and "right".

Comment: @Barmar OK. _port side_ then.  IAC, _port_ is unambiguous to the person's orientation on the craft, or in OP's case cube.

Comment: Port is practically never used outside the context of marine and aircraft. No one would refer to the port side of a cube, they'd just say left or right.

Comment: @Barmar Aside from the Borg, rarely is a cube something someone is moving about in space.  As we are imagining such a space craft, using related terms, especially aeronautical ones a pilot might use is reasonable and we are in the context of a craft moving in 3D.  Left and right are overloaded terms in terms of reference as they first tend to reference from a personal perspective, port/starboard less so as they immediately apply to the craft. L/R can work, I assert P/S work better.

Answer (score 0):

'Left' and 'right' in the political sense are are relative to each other.  The distinction was first drawn in the French revolution. In the French assemblé, supporters of the king sat on his right, while opposition to the king sat on his left.  Clearly the distance they sat to his left or his right was not necessarily a measure of the strength (or extremity) of support or opposition.

Left and Right in more recent times have to do with aspects of a politician's or a party's economic and social position or policies.  It has nothing to do with the whether or not a nation should reject or acquire a monarch or junta. But the politics around the world are a bit like the world as we now know it:  spherical rather than flat.  So the left and right can meet at their respective extremes in Soviet communism and military dictatorship in both of which the mass population find themselves poor and powerless, ruled by a dominant ruling caste, monarchic, religious or military.

The common way of dealing with the 'wings' of politics is the use of the word 'Far' as in 'far' (or sometimes 'extreme') left and right.

Comment: Thank you for a considered answer, and I'm sorry for not being totally unambiguous. I was explicltly referring to geometry, not politics!

Comment: Thank you for a forgiving response:  I should have read the question more carefully.  I suppose "side" must be the best, as mentioned among the other answers.

Answer (score -4):

In math, the extremes of the left-right axis are called -∞ and +∞ .

Comment: This isn't math per se. It's geometry.

Comment: @Lambie you say that like geometry isn't a subset of mathematics

Comment: @Boneist I don't understand that sentence. As far as I can tell, a cube does not have extremes of a left-right axis.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit the example of a cube. You wouldn't say the left face is at negative infinity. You're answering the summary in the title, not the actual question.